# Get legacy params[:action] to work in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm parsing a third-party API that send me a value on an unfortunately attribute called `action`. Since Rails reserves `action` param for controller actions, I'm getting `create` as value instead of the value they send me.

Is there any way to bypass this rails default just for this case so I can read the value the thid-party api is sending me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-request_parameters

You can get access to parameters using request.request_parameters() or something like that and use them.

Comment: that is not working, `request.request_parameters()` returns `{}` and `request.params` return the same `"action"=>"create"`

Answer (score 0):

You can either try `request.POST` or, as a final resort, parse [request.raw_post](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-raw_post).